# testing of data in random forest?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, random-forest

I want to clarify point in random forest literature. In random forest we select random features from a subset of data, i.e it is subset of features from subset of data for a single tree. But when we test the data, let's take a test sample 'v' from the test data. The data has say '5' features.

1. Tree one was constructed using features 3 and 2.
2. Tree two was constructed using features 2,3, and 5.
3. Tree three was constructed using features 1,2 and 3.
4. Tree four was constructed using features 1,4,and 5.

at leaf node we will have probability showing to which class does the 'v' point belongs.

My question is : Will each forest choose same features from the test data sample 'v' as it used when the tree was constructed. ?
for example will tree one will use features 3 and 2. and tree two use feature 2, 3 and 5. respectively

Comment: You're asking whether each tree in the test set looks at the same features that it looked at in the training set?

Comment: The trees in the forest are fixed after fitting. So, when predicting values for new points, each tree will use the same features at each node.

Comment: @surelyourejoking yes I am asking for the same

Comment: @mkt can you provide a link where this is explained

Comment: Should be evident when you read the original Breiman paper.